# Parabolic SAR calculated in Python seems to be reversed

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance, ta-lib

When I use Pandas and the TA-lib library, my Parabolic SAR line is reversed.

This is my CSV records:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import talib



data = pd.read_csv("/content/m4.csv") 
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format="%Y%m%d")
data = data.set_index('Date')

data['SAR'] = talib.SAR(data.High , data.Low, acceleration=0.02, maximum=0.2)
# Plot Parabolic SAR with close price
data[['Close', 'SAR']][:500].plot(figsize=(10,5))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

And this is the result which is exactly a reverse of the expected:

[image]

Comment: `talib`'s docs don't have much detail as to the behaviour of the parameters, you would have to trace it in the [code](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/blob/master/talib/_func.pxi). Have you tried `acceleration=-0.02`?

Comment: can you upload the data? I'll try to debug

Comment: @RichieV has posted a link to just a wrapper, the actual computation is being held inside TA-lib legacy code: `retCode = lib.TA_SAR( 0 , endidx , <double *>(high.data)+begidx , <double *>(low.data)+begidx , acceleration , maximum , &outbegidx , &outnbelement , <double *>(outreal.data)+lookback )`, so the debugging will be painful. All Quant-Libs ought keep as a portability-standard to include, best in a `[TEST-ME]` section of `__doc__`, data-set altogether with nominal ( correct ) outputs, so as to permit cross-portability testing / validation of properly done re-porting ... the rest is easy.

Comment: If this is the only function you are using from talib you could just write your own.